# How can I link two JavaScript objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, indexing, reference

Say I have an object (obj1) where one of the values in obj1 is another object (obj2). Is there any way to make it so that checking for anything in obj1 (e.g. obj1.username) would also check in obj2 (obj1.ob2.username) automatically?

The use case for this is if something doesn't exist in obj1, I would want to also check in obj2 before it returns null.

Example Usage:

```js
var user = {username: "David"} // obj2
var member = {nickname: "Dave", user: user} // obj1

console.log(user.username) // "David"
console.log(user.nickname) // null

console.log(member.username) // "David"
console.log(member.nickname) // "Dave"
```

This is for usage in Node.js.

--Edit--

I forgot to note that members and users are created from classes in a library I'm using to interact with an application called Discord.

When a message is sent an event is triggered and I am handed information like the member object (with a link to the user object inside it).

[Here is the structure of a user.](https://github.com/hydrabolt/discord.js/blob/stable/src/structures/User.js#L9)

[Here is the structure of a member.](https://github.com/hydrabolt/discord.js/blob/stable/src/structures/GuildMember.js#L12)

```
Object.defineProperty(Discord.Member.prototype, 'username', {
    get: function() { return this.user.username; },
    set: function(newValue) { this.user.username = newValue; }
});
```

The above method works as intended, however only for the `username` property. I considered applying this for every property of user, however when I tried iterating through the properties of a created user, some (like [`.createdAt`](https://github.com/hydrabolt/discord.js/blob/stable/src/structures/User.js#L81)) didn't show up in the list.

I understand that I could do it manually and write every defineProperty by hand, but the idea here is that user will be constantly updated with new properties over time, so I would prefer it to do what I described above.

Comment: If a member is a user it seems like a decent usecase for prototype inheritance (or "classes" if that's how you roll).

Comment: write user.prototype = member

Comment: `{get nickname() { return this.user.username }, user}`?

Comment: @binariedMe No.

Comment: I'm using this for a Discord bot application, so member and user are both objects that are given to me (https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) through events like "Message Sent".

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) and inside use [`getter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) to check first if property exists in original and then in other object.

```js
var user = {
  username: "David"
} // obj2

var member = {
  nickname: "Dave",
  user: user,
} // obj1


var pMember = new Proxy(member, {
  get: function(target, prop) {
    if (target[prop]) return target[prop];
    else if (target.user[prop]) return target.user[prop];
  }
});

console.log(pMember.nickname)
console.log(pMember.username)
```

Comment: I can't create a new variable for "member", it needs to be for the member that already exists.

Comment: Member comes from a library's class so I need to change the member objects created from the class. 

`Object.defineProperty(Discord.Member.prototype, 'username', {
 get: function() { return this.user.username; },
 set: function(newValue) { this.user.username = newValue; }
});`

This works for the username property, however I need it to work for all properties of https://github.com/hydrabolt/discord.js/blob/stable/src/structures/User.js#L9. If I iterate through a User I can repeat the defineProperty method, however some properties in there (like createdAt) don't show up when I iterate.

Comment: A warning. A `get` and `set` proxy handler can significantly affect performance for the object you have put a proxy on be careful when using proxies on frequently accessed object. . Also the code answer example is a little dangerous as it does not explicitly check for property existence and will return `undefined` for all properties that are `target[prop] == false && target.user[prop] == false` (note not  ===  false)

Comment: It's not that it didn't work, it's a perfect solution for what I originally described, it's that for my use I'm getting members in hundreds of places across my code, so I need it to be that indexing values in any member automatically checks in member.user too, without me having to replace member everytime, and that the member is still the member given to me in the first place, for passing it back to functions in the library e.g "deleteLastMessages(member, number)".

Comment: Can you extend guildMember with prototype that will get properties so something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1861/?

Comment: Yeah that worked. Would be nice to be able to check the properties of the user without having to call a method, but this is the next best thing.

Comment: Maybe you could instead extend GuildMember class with child class that will return proxy like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1862/ but you will need to customize this to match real `GuildMember` class

Answer (score 0):

Using inheritance:

```
var user = {username: "David"} // obj2
var member =Object.assign(Object.create(user),{nickname: "Dave", user: user}); // obj1

console.log(member.username);
```

http://jsbin.com/nojolizewu/edit?console